# How to change Datastore associated to a Data View on runtime?

Tags: genexus, genexus-dbret

I'm planning to distribute load from my database making a copy on several servers (each server will have the same tables but with different company data).

In order to do this, I will need to programmatically change the Datastore associated to my Data Views. For other tables I'm using the "Before Connect" property.

It's possible to handle this in Genexus?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use dbConnection Data Type.

Just create a variable based on this data type, and use it's methods and properties to set it up when you need it to be changed...